# Buying Bitcoins without identity checks?

Tags: exchanges

Are there any exchanges that offer Bitcoins without identity checks? I would like to remain anonymous while buying the currency.

Comment: I'd prefer an exchange that would accept international bank transfers without identity checks.

Comment: Might exist, but most of these offers will likely be scams. Also keep in mind that this doesn't provide full anonymity, they will still keep the data that shows where the money came from.

Answer (score 1):

[LocalBitcoins](http://localbitcoins.com) provides

- In-person cash trades - can be done complete anonymous. Check "Buy bitcoins with cash" on the site.
- Cash deposits - depending on the bank and the country you may be do cash deposit anonymously